# Python: modify information on list item

Tags: python

I have this piece of Python code:

```
constraints = {
  'signupForms': [{key: form[key] for key in ['id']} for form in signup_forms],
  'groups': [{'id': group[key] for key in ['member_group_id']} for group in groups],
  'authorizedApps': [{key: app[key] for key in ['id']} for app in authorized_apps],
}
for step in len(eda_workflow['steps']):
    eda_workflow['steps'][step]['constaints'] = constraints
```

All I am wanting to do is loop through each of the workflow 'steps' and set their constraints to the same constraints `dict` that is pre-built, but I am just not sure if this is the "pythonic" way

Comment: len() returns an integer, which is not iterable. This code should result in a TypeError.

Comment: @chepner But the function [len()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) returns an integer. How can an integer be iterated over? Experimenting with this construct in 2.7 always causes a TypeError exception.

Comment: @ScottLawson I deleted my comment; I was thinking of a technicality based on how the `for` statement is defined in the grammar. The grammar allows a single item syntactically, but of course when the loop is evaluated, the item must be iterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More Pythonic (and correct, unlike your current code) would be

```
for item in eda_workflow['steps']:
    item['constaints'] = constraints
```

Iterate over the actual items in the list, rather than (as you are attempting to do) over the indices of the list.

Comment: Thanks so much! Was having a "brain fart". I probably should open a new question for this, but is there a way to get the last item during while inside the `for` loop?

Comment: `eda_workflow['steps'][-1]` would still work inside the for loop

Answer (score 4):

The term "Pythonic" is subjective but tying to do it in as little code as possible, you could use the "[map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)" function.  Map runs a function on each item in an iterable.  So you code would look something like this:

```
map(lambda item: item['constaints'] = constraints, eda_workflow['steps'])
```

Although this is less code, it will use up more memory as map will return a list of results.  If you are concerned with memory you should probably use chepner's answer

Comment: Using `map` solely for its side effect and not the list it generates is *not* Pythonic.